# Sum $\sum_{k=0}^{2013}2^ka_{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

let real sequence $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$,such
$$a_{0}=2013,a_{n}=-\dfrac{2013}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k},n\ge 1$$

How find this sum 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2013}2^ka_{k}$$

My idea: since
$$-na_{n}=2013(a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n-1})\cdots\cdots(1)$$
so
$$-(n+1)a_{n+1}=2013(a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n})\cdots\cdots (2)$$
then
$(2)-(1)$,we have
$$na_{n}-(n+1)a_{n+1}=2013a_{n}$$
then
$$(n+1)a_{n+1}=(2013-n)a_{n}$$
then 
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\dfrac{2013-n}{n+1}$$
so
$$\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}\cdot\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\cdots\dfrac{a_{1}}{a_{0}}=\cdots$$
so
$$\dfrac{a_{2013}}{a_{0}}=\dfrac{1}{2013}\cdot\dfrac{2}{2012}\cdots\dfrac{2013}{1}=1?$$
then How can find this sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1 (generating function)**

Let $a(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$, notice

$$a(z)\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)\left( \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty z^\ell\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\right)z^n$$

and 
$$\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)a(z) = \left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n z^n$$
The equality $a_{n}=-\dfrac{2013}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k},\,n\ge 1$ implies

$$\frac{da(z)}{dz} = -2013\frac{a(z)}{1-z}
\quad\iff\quad \frac{d}{dz} \log a(z) = 2013\frac{d}{dz}\log(1-z)$$

and hence
$$a(z) = a_0(1-z)^{2013} = 2013(1-z)^{2013}$$

Since this is a polynomial with degree 2013, we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2013} a_k 2^k = a(2) = 2013 (1-2)^{2013} = -2013$$

**Method 2 (more elementary, appropriate for middle school students)**

Let $b_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k$, we have $b_0 = 2013$ and for $n > 0$,
$$n(b_n-b_{n-1}) = -2013 b_{n-1}\quad\iff\quad  b_n = -\frac{2013 -n}{n}b_{n-1}$$
This implies
$$b_n = (-1)^n \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (2013-k)}{n!} b_0
= (-1)^n \frac{2013!}{n!(2013-n-1)!}
= (-1)^n \binom{2013}{n} (2013-n)$$

Notice $$b_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{2013!}{(n-1)!(2013-n)!} = (-)^{n-1} \binom{2013}{n} n,$$
we obtain

$$a_n = b_n - b_{n-1} = (-1)^n 2013\binom{2013}{n}$$

Using binomial theorem, we can evaluate the desired sum as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2013} a_k 2^k = 2013 \sum_{k=0}^{2013} \binom{2013}{k}(-2)^k = 2013 (1-2)^{2013} = -2013$$

Comment: It's nice methods! Thank you,+1 because this problem is middle school student problem,I think have other methods

Comment: @math110 In your question, you should mention this is a problem for middle school students. In any event, I have cooked up an alternate solution that is more elementary and should be doable by middle school students.

Comment: oh,Nice! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{a_{0}=2013\,,\quad a_{n} = -\,{2013 \over n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}a_{k}\,,\quad
     n \geq 1:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\pars{n + 1}a_{n + 1} - na_{n}=-2013\pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_{k} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}a_{k}} = -2013 a_{n}
> \\[3mm]&\imp\quad
> \pars{n + 1}a_{n + 1} - \pars{n - a_{0}}a_{n} =  0
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1}a_{n + 1}z^{n} - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}na_{n}z^{n}
+a_{0}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=0
\\[3mm]&
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}na_{n}z^{n - 1}
-z\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
+a_{0}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=0
\\[3mm]&
\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
-z\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
+a_{0}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=0
\\[3mm]&
\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
-{a_{0} \over z - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=0
\\[3mm]&
\pars{z - 1}^{-a_{0}}\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}
-a_{0}\pars{z - 1}^{-a_{0} - 1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=0
\\[3mm]&
\partiald{}{z}
\bracks{\pars{z - 1}^{-a_{0}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}}=0
\quad\imp\quad\pars{z - 1}^{-a_{0}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} = -a_{0}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}=a_{0}\pars{1 - z}^{a_{0}}
> =a_{0}\sum_{n = 0}^{a_{0}}{a_{0} \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}z^{n}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{z = -2}$:
$$
\color{#00F}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{2013}2^{k}a_{k}} = 2013\pars{1 - 2}^{2013} = \color{#00F}{\large -2013}
$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write out the expression of $a_{n}$ and find its regular :

$a_{0}=a_{0}$

$a_{1}=-2013a_{0}$

$a_{2}=-\frac{2013}{2}(a_{0}+a_{1})$

$a_{3}=-\frac{2013}{3}(a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2})$

$......$

$sum$$=a_{0}(1-2\cdot{2013}-4\cdot{\frac{2013}{2}}-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)$
$+a_{1}(-4\cdot{\frac{2013}{2}}-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)$$+a_{2}(-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)+......$

then by the symmetric property :

$\Longrightarrow$$a_{0}(-2\cdot{2013}-4\cdot{\frac{2013}{2}}-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)$
$+a_{1}(-4\cdot{\frac{2013}{2}}-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)$$+a_{2}(-8\cdot{\frac{2013}{3}}-......)+......$$=-2a_{0}((a_{0}+a_{0}+4/3a_{0}+......)$$+(a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......)$$+4/3a_{2}+......)$$\Longrightarrow$$((a_{0}+a_{0}+4/3a_{0}+......)$$+(a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......)$$+4/3a_{2}+......)$$=a_{0}(1+1+4/3+......-a_{0}-4/3a_{0}-......-4/3\cdot1/2(a_{0}+a_{1})-......)$

$=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot$$(a_{1}+a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......+a_{2}+4/3a_{2}+......)$$=$

$\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}$$\cdot$$(a_{2}+a_{2}+4/3a_{2}+......+a_{3}+4/3a_{3}+......)$
$=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}$$\cdot......\cdot{\frac{a_{2012}}{a_{2013}}}=1$

i add a supplement to this proof :

$((a_{0}+a_{0}+4/3a_{0}+......)$$+(a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......)$$+4/3a_{2}+......)$$=a_{0}(1+1+4/3+......-a_{0}-4/3a_{0}-......-4/3\cdot1/2(a_{0}+a_{1})-......)$$=a_{0}(1+4/3+......-4/3a_{0}-......-4/3\cdot1/2(a_{0}+a_{1})-......)$

$=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{t_{1}}\cdot$$(a_{1}-a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......+a_{2}+4/3a_{2}+......)$$=$

$\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}\cdot{t_{1}\cdot{t_{2}}}\cdot$$(4/3a_{2}-4/3a_{2}+......+a_{3}+4/3a_{3}+......)$

$=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}$$\cdot......\cdot{\frac{a_{2012}}{a_{2013}}}\cdot{t_{1}}\cdot{t_{2}}\cdot......\cdot{t_{n}}\cdot$$(4/3a_{1}+4/8a_{1}+......+8/4a_{2}+16/5a_{2}+......+16/5a_{3}+......)$

where, $t_{i}=\frac{a_{i}}{a_{0}}$

and we continue our procedure ,which deduce that :

$((a_{0}+a_{0}+4/3a_{0}+......)$$+(a_{1}+4/3a_{1}+......)$$+4/3a_{2}+......)$

$=\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}$$\cdot......\cdot{\frac{a_{2012}}{a_{2013}}}\cdot{t_{1}}\cdot{t_{2}}\cdot......\cdot{t_{n}}$$=(-1)^2=1$

that is because if we can omit all $a_{0}$, then $a_{1}=a_{1}$

if we can omit all $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$, then $a_{2}=\frac{3}{4}a_{2}$$\Longrightarrow$$\frac{4}{3}a_{2}=a_{2}$

......

so we can use $t_{i}$ to omit the one more surplus term in each step,so on, we can repeat our procedure and get our last result !

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry, i omit some details !

by the symmetric property, $a_{0}=-a_{2013}$$,$$a_{1}=-a_{2012}$$,......$

the hint is :

$(a_{2}+4/3a_{2}+......+4/3a_{3}+......)/(ta_{0})=-a_{1}/a_{0}(a_{1}-4/3a_{1}-......-4/3a_{2}-......)$

we assume that :

$t_{1}=\frac{(a_{2}+4/3a_{2}+......+4/3a_{3}+......)}{(-a_{1}-4/3a_{1}-......-4/3a_{2}-......)}$

$t_{2}=\frac{(a_{3}+4/3a_{3}+......+4/3a_{4}+......)}{(-a_{2}-4/3a_{2}-......-4/3a_{3}-......)}$

so,

$a_{0}(1+1+4/3+......-a_{0}-4/3a_{0}-......-4/3\cdot1/2(a_{0}+a_{1})-......)$$=$$(\frac{a_{0}}{a_{1}}\cdot{\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}}$$\cdot......\cdot{\frac{a_{2012}}{a_{2013}}})\cdot{\frac{a_{0}}{a_{2013}}}\cdot$$t_{1}\cdot{t_{2}}......\cdot{t_{n}}$$=t_{1}\cdot{t_{2}}......\cdot{t_{n}}$
$=\frac{(a_{n-1}+4/3a_{n-1}+......+4/3a_{n-2}+......)}{(-a_{1}-4/3a_{1}-......-4/3a_{2}-......)}=1$

therefore, your solution holds !